# where to buy the raspberry pi 7" touchscreen display board separately?

Tags: display, touchscreen, screen, gertboard, diy

My raspberry pi 7" touchscreen display board black plastic connector (BROWN CONNECTION ABOVE RPI DISPLAY LETTERING) that holds the ribbon [image]to the raspberry pi broke and I am looking for a replacement display adapter board. However, I have been unable to find a place online that sells JUST the display board. I don't want to pay another $70 for the display and the adapter board, there is no issues with the display. Is there anyone that can help me. I attached a picture of what I need to replace. Otherwise, can you tell me how to replace the plastic connector/clip on the display board (if possible)? Picture of the board in question [![
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cALkK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cALkK.jpg)is attached.

Comment: That's extremely frustrating. Why can you buy other boards separately, but not this one? Can I super glue the ribbon or is there another way to keep the ribbon in place? I don't want to have to drop another $70 on a new display. Seems dumb. I thought the point if Raspberry Pi was to be an inexpensive computer. I guess I'll just buy a smaller display.

Comment: The whole point of "inexpensive computers" is to make money by selling associated accessories or services, just like those $1 mobile phones which come with an expensive plan. More to the point, asking where to buy something is off-topic. You can try to ask "how to repair" instead, but I doubt this connector can be easily repaired. Superglue will likely ruin the electrical connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

It's not available as a replacement part. You can only buy the whole unit as a complete assembly.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Super glue was one thing I was thinking about, but figured it would not help the connection. There was a point that microcenter sold the board separately, so you could choose to connect it to the display yourself, but they no longer do.