# What is the name of this clip / connector?

Tags: display

I bought a Raspberry Pi Display v1.1 but the clip where panel 1 connects is missing (a brown clip, on a white connector). What is the name and size of this clip / connector?

See here [Someone with the clip](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93003/where-to-buy-the-raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display-board-separately)

Missing clip:

[image: Missing clip]

Comment: If you just bought it I would return it. That linked post suggests you can't buy the clip separately. A small piece of cardboard or plastic might work.

Comment: @CoderMike
Yeah I might do that. I'll leave the post just in case someone knows or needs an answer. 

The linked post is talking about the big brown connector with black clip, not the white connector with brown clip I am interested in.

Comment: you cannot buy that clip separately ... you have to buy the whole connector, so change your question to ask about the connector

Comment: @jsotola Adjusted as suggested, any clue what the connector is called?

Comment: it is an FPC connector ... a better place to ask is at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions ... focus the question and the picture on the connector and the cable ... provide the exact width of the cable and the pin spacing